# Display message if there are no search results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a message in table when no result found (Sorry, no entry found. Please extend your search"). Do you have an idea how can I do this ?

My code currently:

```js
$('#Search').on('keyup', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");

  $('#Data').find('tr').each(function() {
    if (!($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).not('#header').hide();
    }
    if (($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="Search" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher un nom ou prénom" /></div>
<table id="Data">
  <thead>
    <tr id="header">
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Dupont</td>
    <td>Pierre</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bertrand</td>
    <td>Philippe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>François</td>
    <td>Xavier</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you

Comment: Put your html code too.

Comment: Just put it in the `else` block? Also, your `if` block appears to be duplicated so you should just combine them into one.

Comment: I added the HML code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. Count number of items that are not shown, if this number equals with number of all `tr`s, show that `td`.

```js
$('#Search').on('keyup', function() {
  $("#noData").remove();
  var value = $(this).val();
  var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");
  var sw = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  $('#Data').find('tr').each(function() {
    counter++;
    if (!($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).not('#header').hide();
      sw++;
    } else if (($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
  if (sw == counter) {
    $("#Data").append(`<tr id="noData">
      <td colspan="2">No data</td>
    </tr>`);
  } else {
    $("#noData").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="Search" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher une monture..." /></div>
<table id="Data">
  <thead>
    <tr id="header">
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Dupont</td>
    <td>Pierre</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bertrand</td>
    <td>Philippe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>François</td>
    <td>Xavier</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you but when you erase the Search box, it displays some "No data" rows.

Comment: Yes. I saw that. sometimes that happened! I am trying to solve that. give me some time @Garrosh

Comment: Check it now, I forget to remove that `td` at the first of each search! @Garrosh

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the job-

```
    var table = $('#Data');
    var emptyMessageRow = $('<tr>Sorry, no entry found. Please extend your search</tr>');

    function _findMatch() {
       var isMatchAvailable = false;
       table.find('tr').each(function () {
          var matchFound = $(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0;
          if (!matchFound) {
             $(this).not('#header').hide();
          } else {
             $(this).show();
             isMatchAvailable = true;
          }
       });
       return isMatchAvailable;
    }

    var isMatchAvailable = _findMatch();
    if (!isMatchAvailable) {
        table.append(emptyMessageRow);
    } else {
        emptyMessageRow.remove();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem simpler, has the same duplicate check for matches, and has a number of issues (including adding a _new_ row for every non-match, and then promptly removing it if a match was found somewhere else)